# SVG to JPG / PNG

Tags: php, image, image-manipulation, svg

Is there any working module to **convert** a 
**SVG** image **into** a pixel format like **JPEG** or **PNG**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the Batik toolkit. Specifically the rasterizer:

http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html

Answer (score 6):

If you're using PEAR you can the XML_svg2image package (http://pear.php.net/package/XML_svg2image/). If not you should take a look at ImageMagick command line tool (http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php). The convert program is quite simple to use : http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php#usage

Answer (score 5):

If you have imagemagick installed (the tool, not sure how it would work with the PHP package), it can be as simple as:

```
<?php
  `convert infile.svg outfile.jpg`
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

We can also use command line interface such as inkscape to achieve it. Download inkscape from [inkscape.org](http://inkscape.org)

Open Terminal/command prompt
Type command as:

single file conversion

```
inkscape -z --file=original.svg --export-png=converted.png --export-area-drawing --export-dpi=200
```

Batch conversion of SVG's to PNG can be achieved as follows :

```
for i in *.svg; 
   do inkscape -z --file=$i --export-png=$i.png --export-area-drawing --export-dpi=200; 
done
```

--export-area-drawing : This will only export the drawing area of SVG file and not the whole document area.

Comment: Inkscape is _not_ a command line tool (it has however a command line interface), but apart from that, it's a valid (and good to know) answer. +1

Comment: Thanks Boldewyn for elaborating. Yes, It is command line interface and not a tool. I converted more than 2K files in few moments. so thought to share this.